# shim existing property on window

Tags: javascript

Due to obscure browser compatibility issues, I'd like to be able to intercept attempts to "get" a property on window (pageYOffset). I've determined that I can purely override the property like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "pageYOffset", {
    get: function () { return SOME_CONSTANT; }
});
```

But I want to be able to read the "base" value of pageYOffset and use it in a new calculation.  If pageYOffset were a function, I could shim it like this:

```
var base = window.pageYOffset;
window.pageYOffset = function() {
    var tempValue = base();
    return tempValue * SOME_CONSTANT;
}
```

Is there an equivalent way to grab a reference to the getter function of a property, so I can still call it after it's no longer publicly accessible?

(I'm aware this is a very questionable thing to want to do, but I'm ready to face the consequences. Also, the only browsers I need to support are IE11 and Chrome.)

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'pageYOffset')` ought to, but doesn't, work.